# Prove the projection map $X \times Y \xrightarrow{\pi_X} X$ is an open map.

Tags: general-topology

This is my problem: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces with topologies $T_X$ and $T_Y$, respectively.  Recall, a map $X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ is called *open* if $\forall U \in T_X, f(U) \in T_Y$.  Verify that the projection map $X \times Y \xrightarrow{\pi_X} X$ is an open map.  Your result should naturally generalize to the other projection map as well.

This is how I approached the problem: By definition let $S$ be the product topology given by $S=\{\pi_{X}^{-1}(U) \mid U \in T_X\} \cup \{\pi_{Y}^{-1}(V) \mid V \in T_Y\}$. Want to show $\forall A \in S, \pi_X (A) \in T_X$.

Note:

$A= \begin{cases} \pi_{X}^{-1}(U)=\{(x,y) \mid x \in U, y \in Y\} \\
\pi_{Y}^{-1} (V)=\{(x,y) \mid x \in X, y \in V \} \end{cases}$

If $A=\pi_{X}^{-1}(U), \pi_X(A)=U \in T_X$. If $A=\pi_{Y}^{-1}(V), \pi_X(A)=X \in T_X$. Therefore, $A \in T_X$ and $\pi_X$ is an open map. The proof follows similarly for $\pi_Y(B)=V \in T_Y$.

Is there any other way to approach this problem/ is my logic and solution correct?

Comment: I think showing the projection is open on basis elements of $X$ is enough.

Comment: Your $S$ is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a non-empty subset of $X\times Y$ is open if and only if it's of the form:
$$\bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i\times V_i)$$
where $U_i$ are non-empty open subsets of $X$, $V_i$ are open subsets of $Y$.
Since $\pi_X$ is the projection on the first component, we have:
\begin{align*}
\pi_X\Big[\bigcup_{i\in I} (U_i\times V_i)\Big]
&=\bigcup_{i\in I} \pi_X[U_i\times V_i]\\
&=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i .
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you use the surjectivity of $\pi_X$?

Comment: Surjectivity is, in fact, unecessary.